# How do I add basic authentication to a Python REST request?

Tags: python, web-services, authentication, rest, http-post

I have the following simple Python code that makes a simple post request to a REST service -

```
params= { "param1" : param1,
          "param2" : param2,
          "param3" : param3 }
xmlResults = urllib.urlopen(MY_APP_PATH, urllib.urlencode(params)).read()
results = MyResponseParser.parse(xmlResults)
```

The problem is that the url used to call the REST service will now require basic authentication (username and password). How can I incorporate a username and password / basic authentication into this code, as simply as possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it serve to pass the required parameters as part of the `params` dictionary? Or does your target service require you to make another explicit call to authenticate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If basic authentication = HTTP authentication, use this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

username = 'foo'
password = 'bar'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, MY_APP_PATH, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

params= { "param1" : param1,
          "param2" : param2,
          "param3" : param3 }

xmlResults = urllib2.urlopen(MY_APP_PATH, urllib.urlencode(params)).read()
results = MyResponseParser.parse(xmlResults)
```

If not, use `mechanize` or `cookielib` to make an additional request for logging in. But if the service you access has an XML API, this API surely includes auth too.

**2016 edit:** By all means, use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library! It provides all of the above in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

You may want a library to abstract out some of the details. I've used [restkit](http://github.com/benoitc/restkit) to great effect before. It handles HTTP auth.