# XSLT-templates in Django - what about 'private' things?

Tags: xml, django, xslt

I want to use XSLT as a template language in Django project.

So the plan is:

1. Create some trivial views that just give me some XML. Like this:

   xsl = libxslt.parseStyleSheetDoc(libxml2.parseFile('stylesheet.xsl'))

   ## ...

   xsl.applyStylesheet(xml_data)
2. Create the XSLTs that will get the data from the XMLs.

The questions are:

- How can I use several XMLs? If I use *document()* function - what URI should I pass there (some kind of http://localhost:8000/my_django_app/my_view.xml)?
- How can I get 'private' data - the things that need authentication (for example, number of messages in user's mailbox)? As I understand, xsl.applyStylesheet does not know anything about user or one's rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The document() function path would be relative to the path of the main document.
- The private XML URLs would be secured using [RESTful authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702370/how-do-i-add-basic-authentication-to-a-python-rest-request) and unstyled XML retrieved using [ssi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#s-ssi).

In RESTful design, whatever means used to store and process permanent data is also used to store and process temporary data. Secondly, each state is identified as a resource that has a URL, so we can query and manipulate it at will, syndicate the URL, and associate CRUD actions with HTTP methods.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674217/building-django-template-files-with-xslt) might be helpful.